# How to insert large string in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, uilabel

i Have a large String and i want to display that in UILabel,but that displays only half of that... how can i got full string even if it 2 lines..?

The code i am used :

```
label.text =@"Kellogg's® All-Bran® Bran Buds® cereal";
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[cell addSubview:label];
```

it displays only `Kellogg's® All-Bran.`
Thank you,
Anand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where u r declaring label use this

```
UILabel *lable=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 250, 20)];
```

or if u do not want to do this then do this

```
 lable.frame=CGRectMake(50, 5, 250, 20);
```

Comment: UILabel *lable=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 250, 20)];

Comment: if it is more than that string how can we display the string?

Comment: UILabel *label =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10, 250, 60 )];
  label.text =@"Kellogg's® All-Bran® Bran Buds® cereal";
  label.numberOfLines = 2;
  label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
  [self.view addSubview:label];

Comment: the problem is in ur height of the view it cannot show two line. do it something like that

Answer (score 1):

Another approach mich more dynamic in nature could be by using

```
CGSize expTSize = [yourLabel.text sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font];
```

You can fix the width upto some value and then divide the width of the above by your fixed width that will give you the number of lines as well. Hence finally you can use the above size variable to reset the frame of the label.

Hope this also works for you, if it does please communicate.